# My reputation is 666; how do I change it?

Tags: discussion, fun

I've noticed today that my reputation on ServerFault corresponds to the number of the beast.

It makes me very unhappy.

[image]

I don't have in mind any interesting ServerFault-related question which could receive upvotes (and obviously, with such reputation, I'm damned to receive no upvotes any longer), so would it be appropriate to post a bad question or a bad answer intentionally to receive downvotes?

If not, what else should I do to make this unholy reputation number change?

Comment: Why not just go and downvote a bad answer and not waste everyone here's time ?

Comment: No one should be afraid of [Emperor Nero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_of_the_Beast#Nero) in this day and age.

Comment: You can ask to get suspended too, your reputation will be show as *1*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although <s>Journeyman Geek</s> an anonymous voter already solved that, another approach is to add a great answer to one of the [44'000+ unanswered questions](https://serverfault.com/questions?sort=unanswered) (or any other question for that matter).

Comment: Alas, no. If I were petty and vindictive, downvoting would *clearly* not be what I did.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek hence the edit and correction from my earlier assumption :)

Answer (score 6):

Someone downvoted you. Now your reputation is 664. Now *make sure* you do not get exactly 2 reputation points more.

Comment: And he also needs to hope that nobody downvotes one of his questions and answers, then upvotes another of his questions...